# Build .ipa from Cocos2dx on windows or linux (not on MaxOS)

Tags: c++, ios, build, cocos2d-x, ipa

Can I build an .ipa file for deploying on iOS with Cocos2dx code on Windows or Linux. I don't have any MacOS available. What are the options?

Comment: An IPA is just a renamed ZIP file. But you also need to code sign the executable for (adhoc) distribution. There are tools though that allow you to code sign in the cloud, but my guess is they'll want you to use their entire toolset.

Comment: I never know it. I though I have to got a Mac to do it. Learnt sth today! Thanks @LearnCocos2D